# RSA key pair is not working

Tags: java, rsa, private-key, public-key

here is my key generation:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = null;
                try {
                    keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
                    keyGen.initialize(1024);
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String publicKey=  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(keyGen.genKeyPair().getPublic().getEncoded());
                String privateKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(keyGen.genKeyPair().getPrivate().getEncoded());}
```

here is my signed token generation code

```
private String generateRSASignedToken(JWTClaimsSet claimsSet) {
            SignedJWT signedJwt  = new SignedJWT(new JWSHeader(JWSAlgorithm.RS256), claimsSet);

            RSASSASigner signer = new RSASSASigner(getPrivateKey());
            String token= null;
            try {
                    signedJwt.sign(signer);
                    token = signedJwt.serialize();

            } catch (JOSEException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return token;
        }
```

getting public and private key

```
private  RSAPrivateKey getPrivateKey() {
                java.security.Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
                try(InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("private.key")){
                String privatekey = IOUtils.toString(stream, Charset.defaultCharset().toString());
                System.out.println("after: "+privatekey);
                byte[] key =  Base64.getDecoder().decode(privatekey);
                PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(key);
                KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                return (RSAPrivateKey) kf.generatePrivate(spec);}
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }


            private  RSAPublicKey getPublicKey(){
              try(InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("public.key")){
              String publickey = IOUtils.toString(stream, Charset.defaultCharset().toString());
              System.out.println("after: "+publickey);
              byte[] key = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publickey);
              X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(key);
              KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
              return (RSAPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(spec);}
                catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                      return null;
                }}
```

token verification :

```
String token = generateRSASignedToken(claimsSet);
                JWSVerifier verifier = new RSASSAVerifier(getPublicKey());
                SignedJWT jwt=null;
                try {
                    jwt = SignedJWT.parse(token);
                    System.out.println(jwt.verify(verifier));
                } catch (ParseException | JOSEException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

every thing looks fine from token generation part to getting public and private key but verification part is not working. It is printing false for the key pair generated. It was working fine with key pair I got from online tool(which I can't use due to licensing problem) but not when I generated keys.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
String publicKey  = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(keyGen.genKeyPair().getPublic().getEncoded());
String privateKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(keyGen.genKeyPair().getPrivate().getEncoded());
```

*Every* time you call `genKeyPair()` a new key pair is generated. Thus `publicKey` and `privateKey` come from different and unrelated key pairs. The solution is simply to save the key pair just generated, e.g.

```
KeyPair kp = keyGen.genKeyPair();
String publicKey  = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(kp.getPublic().getEncoded());
String privateKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(kp.getPrivate().getEncoded());
```

NOTE: there may be other problems with the code, this is the first one I spotted.

Comment: yes I generated the key one time only and then removed that keygen part from the code itself and used the key generated for signing and verification but it didn't work as explained above

Comment: i tried generating keys using open ssl and some other online tools and for that it works totaly fine